# How do I get an hex file generated by SDCC to be simulated in Pic Simulator IDE?

Tags: linux, simulation, pic, sdcc

I have been searching workarounds for many days with no luck.
PIC Simulator keeps telling me that the checksum of the hex file is wrong.
I already tried changing SDCC‘s hex file output format many times and tried all of them but it is the same error with all of them.

Also, A recommendation for a simulator like PIC Simulator IDE for me to use in GNU/Linux is appreciated, I have tried GPSim many times in different distros but could never get a single program to simulate. So I don’t trust it so far... and because it keeps crashing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mario, it is actually easier than your answer, Just use output format ihx32 in the linker and it will work out of the box.

Comment: Gonna check it, thanks for helping me. *edit*: PERFECT thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it myself, if SDCC‘s output format is IHX.

```
objcopy -O ihex input-file output-file
```

It will be perfectly simulable by PIC Simulator IDE.